# Why does nested loop with list.add gives O(n^4) time complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I came across this question for the Big O time complexity of this code snippet:
It is guaranteed that the time complexity for the following code is O(n^4).

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = n; i>=1; i--)           //n 
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)       //n     
        if(!list.contains(i*j))     //n?    
            list.add(i*j);          //1?
```

**My Question**: Why is it O(n^4) instead of O(n^3)?

Comment: What's `n` initialized to?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken This is the complete question. It doesn't matter what `n` is to determine the Big O...you can assume it as some number greater than 1.

Comment: I was suspecting it could be due to the `add` because arraylist are backed by array which double itself when filled and all elements have to be copied to the new array.

Comment: But, that would just add another constant onto the n (because the `if` is not `looping` around the `add`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list` has about `n^2/2` entries[*], so the lookup `list.contains(i*j)` is `O(n^2)` not `O(n)`

*: some less because duplicates are not added, but i guess enough to count as `n^2`

Comment: How does `list.contains(i*j)` gives O(n^2) here? Mind elaborating?

Comment: Ignoring the duplicates; at the end you will have added `(n^2)/2` entries to the list. `contains` has `O(r)` where `r` is the number of entries in list, hence `O(n^2/2) =  O(n^2)`

Comment: Nice observation!

Comment: @k5_ If there are 3 layers of nested for loops, all looping n number of times, in this case, the `.contains()` will be O(n^3) ? Which means the overall complexity becomes O(n^6) ? Is this the correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

`list.contains(i*j)` happens in **O(n^2)** as i and j are dependents on n ( if linear search is used ). Basically it will be 2 loops in O(n) nested and an operation of of O(n^2) inside the nested loop and hence `O(n^4)`.

Comment: `i*j` is just an integer, so it will be `list.contains(x)` where `x = i*j`.  So it should just a be linear, `O(n)` lookup time.

Comment: @Bill the complexity in this case depends on the number entries in the list, not on the parameter value.

Comment: @Bill In terms of x i.e i*j it is linear but in terms of n it is quadratic.

Comment: @k5_, that was my point in commenting.  It should just be a linear lookup  because the parameter is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bill linear to r where r is the number of entries in the list. but r is n^2 (the n from the first loop)

Comment: @k5_, Doh! of course.  I was getting my wires crossed.  `O(n^2)` in this case because the list will have `n^2` elements, worst case.  Sorry, my confusion.